# Finding sum of a series

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

How do I find the sum of all fractions whose denominator only have factors of 2 and or 3? Thanks!

Comment: Most likely it diverges. But honestly, I'm not sure I understand the question, It would be nice if you could be clearer about what you're asking and what you've tried so far.

Comment: That would include $\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\cdots\right)$. Unfortunately, the series diverges. And this is just those with a numerator of $1$.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales you seem to be overcounting some of the terms, for example $\frac{1}{6}$ will occur because of $\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{3}$ while also occurring because of $\frac{1}{3}\cdot \frac{1}{2}$.  You can correct this by subtracting something convenient.  This is of course assuming the question is about finding the sum of all fractions of the form $\frac{1}{q}$ where $2\mid q$ or $3\mid q$.

Comment: The question is made more complicated if it is instead asking to sum all fractions of the form $\frac{1}{q}$ where $q=2^a\cdot 3^b$, i.e. the *only* prime factors of $q$ are $2$ or $3$.  That one actually, I would expect to converge.

Comment: @JMoravitz I apologize that is the question. Prime factors of 2 and or 3. I will edit.

Comment: It's clear from the comments but not what the question asks: You don't want to include $5/6$ but just $1/6$, right?

Comment: For this new question, can you somehow relate your summation to $(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+\dots+\frac{1}{2^n}+\dots)(1+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{9}+\dots+\frac{1}{3^m}+\dots)$?

Comment: @JMoravitz You are correct.

Comment: I see... So then by using geometric series for finding sum, I would get 1 times 1/2 which is 1/2.

Comment: @user7697538 notice that the way I phrased the question, we are including $1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3}$ and other fractions of the form $\frac{1}{2^a}$ and $\frac{1}{3^b}$ in our sum.  If $1$ is in our summation, surely the total sum is greater than $\frac{1}{2}$.  You seem to be mixing up your formulae for geometric sums for when the start of the index is $1$ as compared to the start of the index is $0$.  You have $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\dots+\frac{1}{2^n}+\dots = 1$ but you have $1+\frac{1}{2}+\dots+\frac{1}{2^n}+\dots = 2$, not $1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be perfectly clear, the question I am answering here is how to find the sum of the series $\sum\limits_{q\in Q} q$ where $$Q=\{\frac{1}{x}~:~x=2^a3^b~\text{for some}~a,b\in\Bbb N\}$$

That is to say $Q=\{1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{6},\frac{1}{8},\frac{1}{9},\frac{1}{16},\frac{1}{18},\frac{1}{24},\frac{1}{27},\dots\}$ is the set of all fractions with numerator $1$ and denominator a natural number whose only prime factors include $2$ and $3$.

---

Step one: recognize that there is a natural bijection between $Q$ and $\Bbb N\times \Bbb N$

> From $\Bbb N\times \Bbb N$ to $Q$, have $(a,b)\mapsto \frac{1}{2^a3^b}$

Step two: recognize then that we can rewrite the sum using this bijection to our advantage

$\sum\limits_{q\in Q}q = $

> $\sum\limits_{q\in Q}q = \sum\limits_{(a,b)\in\Bbb N} \frac{1}{2^a3^b}=\sum\limits_{a=0}^\infty \sum\limits_{b=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^a3^b}$

Step three: recognize that we can break apart the expression on the right as a product of summations

> $\sum\limits_{a=0}^\infty \sum\limits_{b=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^a3^b}=\left(\sum\limits_{a=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^a}\right)\cdot\left(\sum\limits_{b=0}^\infty \frac{1}{3^a}\right)$

Step four: recognize each of the summations used in the final expression above and evaluate.

> $\sum\limits_{a=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^a} = \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{2}}=2$ and $\sum\limits_{b=0}^\infty\frac{1}{3^b}=\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{3}}=\frac{3}{2}$ so the product is $2\cdot \frac{3}{2}=3$

Comment: I calculated the sums wrong, silly mistake. Thank you so much!! You're amazing!

Comment: There are a number of details left out intentionally for you to complete to have a fully rigorous answer, such as proving that the bijection described is in fact a bijection and proving that the manipulations made are valid.  They will be, but it deserves additional explanation